# JSN air show list horizontal (virtuemart newest products)

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I have Joomla 2.5.9 with Virtuemart 2.0.20b

I am using the JSN Air template.
It all works perfect, except offcourse for 1 thing.

I have added a module with the VirtueMart Product module to show the newest products.
I positioned this in the mainbody-bottom. But the products are now shown in a vertical list, instead of a horizontal list.

Is this something which is not supported in the free version of the template? Or am I doing something wrong? Or should I use a module class suffix?

When I go to the frontpage of the webshop, the products are shown horizontal, so there it works fine.

When I use the module in another template (standard Beez2) it shows the products horizontal, so the issue is not in the VirtueMart module. It's in the AIR template.

Hope someone can help me.

Kind regards,
Robert

Answer (score 0):

It is solved!
I had to enter some VirtueMart CSS code into business.css (which is from the template).